# How To Deploy AWS CloudFormation Template Across Region?

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda, aws-sdk

I was trying to deploy AWS services using cloudFormation. I was successful with deploy for particular region. Now i wanted to deploy some of AWS Services in different region for example i have EC2, Lambda and S3 for deployment and i have to deploy EC2 and lambda on us-west region and S3 on EU-East and US-WEST region.
Can this possible with one template. 
I went thought [AWS Stack Set](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacksets-getting-started-create.html) but i think this will deploy to all AWS Service to all mention region. I wanted to have some AWS Services to some region and some with only one specific region.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the CLI, your best option is to have multiple profiles configured and then perform two deployments with different profiles for each deployment. Secondarily, you can use parameters as input to your template and use a conditional statement to deploy different resources based on the region you're targeting. Relevant links -

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=162459